# Cannot copy a sheet when the sheet has a button in EPPlus?

Tags: c#, xlsx, epplus

I can't copy a sheet when it has a button in it. It will raise an unhandled exception of type

> System.InvalidOperationException" occurred in EPPlus.dll. The Inner Exception is: Cannot access a closed Stream.

---

```
  FileInfo templateFile = new FileInfo("Original-With-Button.xlsx");
  FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo("Copy-With-Button.xlsx");
  using (var package = new ExcelPackage(newFile, templateFile))
  {
     package.Workbook.Worksheets.Copy("Sheet1", "Sheet2");                
     package.Save();
  }
```

If I remove the button in Sheet1, the copy works fine. How can I copy the sheet with button?

Comment: I see the same.  If I had to guess, Epplus doesn't support OLE/ActiveX controls.  Could post a ticket on their git hub page to confim.

Comment: I had done, but i got no answer.